# Separate launcher icon for companion configuration activity of a watch face (Android Wear)

Tags: android, wear-os

I implemented a watch face with a configuration activity on the mobile device. The configuration activity works fine when launched from within the Android Wear app.

However, I'd like to create an extra icon that launches the configuration activity like a normal app, from outside Android Wear. When I simply implement the activity as a normal app in AndroidManifest, like below, it fails to communicate with the watch.

Ideally, the extra launcher should start the configuration activity together with the Android Wear app, if it's not running already.

```
<activity
        android:label="Companion Configuration"
        android:name=".ConfigActivity" >
         <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: What architecture are you currently using to communicate between the handheld config activity and your code on Wear? The answer to your question will depend on what you've already got.

Comment: I use the standard Wearable Data Layer APIs from Google.

Answer (score 0):

It's nothing to do with the launcher icon - or really anything on the phone side.

What you need is for your Wear app to launch when data is changed in your phone-side configuration activity, and that's all set up in the wearable app. It's well documented at https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/events.html#Listen

In your case (since your watch app isn't running yet when the phone `Activity` is launched), you'll probably want to subclass `WearableListenerService`. This will get run by the system when data is changed on the phone, and you can do whatever is appropriate for your app when that happens.

Comment: That's exactly how I did it. I followed this example: https://developer.android.com/samples/WatchFace/index.html. The problem is that phone side doesn't connect to the watch when it's not launched from within the Google Wear app.

Comment: Then you've got something else wrong in your Wear app. It's impossible to say what without seeing some of that code; there are numerous pitfalls in making the Data API work.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working by using the Wearable.DataApi instead of the Wearable.MessageApi

I had been using the Wearable.MessageApi to update watch from phone and that requires a peerid which i guess is generated by the wear app. I put a if/then statement to check if peerid is null and if so use the DataApi instead and works from inside the wear app and from app drawer